# Can i use complex condition using XPath in Filter Mediator WSO2?

Tags: xpath, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have a condition written in SQL Language that i would like to use it in Filter Mediator XPath but it didn't work and it give me an error .

NB : I got variable value from JSON payload .

**Actual SQL Condition**

```
(!ISNULL(a) && a== 2 && b== 1) || c== 5
```

**Expected XPath Condition**

```
(//a=2 AND //b=1) OR //c=5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

```
<filter xpath="boolean(//a/text() = '1' and //b/text() = '2') or //c/text() = '3'">
    <then>
        <log>
            <property value="===== TRUE" name="MSG"/>
        </log>
    </then>
    <else>
        <log>
            <property value="===== FALSE" name="MSG"/>
        </log>
    </else>
</filter>
```